# How to show category tree on magento website according to a particular Store Products and not the full default category in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a Magento website where I want to show categories according to the available products in a Store. If there is one or more products in a sub-category then that sub-category should list in top menu of the website with its parent category.

For instance, I am in my Store with name suppose **Lee Store**. Now I just want to see only **Women** and **Men** categories. About sub-categories if I have products only in Women(products available in all sub categories) and Men > Tops > Hoodies & Sweatshirts, then in Men category following sub-categories should not show:

```
Men > Tops > Jackets
Men > Tops > Tees
Men > Tops > Tanks
Men > Bottoms
```

Also other categories should not show:

```
Whats New
Gear
Training
Sale
```

[Please see this screenshot for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgmKI.png)

**I'm using Magento version 2.3.2**

Along with website, Can we get the same result in Rest API where we have Store id and all Products of that store. Now on the basis of these values can we get Categories/Sub-categories in proper tree format But only those categories should list which have products for that particular store.

Thanks in Advance.. :-)